What's the difference between "can" and "will be able to" in this scenario?
I made up this conversation for the teaching material for my class and felt that the two expressions were very similar, but then a native English speaker told me that they had subtle differences.
A: We've got lost. What should we do?
B: Just call Jack. He grew up here.

If we tell him what we see, he can give us directions.
If we tell him what we see, he'll be able to give us directions.

What's the subtle difference in meaning that exists here?

It should be "We're [are] lost" because you are talking about an established fact in the present.

What did the "native speaker" say? You need to include all your research and that incudes the answers you received on ELL. P.S Be carful, there is more than one user who visit both sites.

The question on ELL is "can" vs "be able to"; "will be able to" is the future of "be able to"; there's no future of "can".

I’m voting to close this question because it is a cross-posting.

And now it's been migrated it's a duplicate.

I want to agree with Chasly.  “To be able” refers to the specific abilities of the subject.  Bob is able to run a 6-minute mile; Joe is not.
“Can” speaks to possibility generally.  Not only can the person do it, it is doable.
The difference is very subtle — and arguably only rhetorical, since any “capability” is about the intersection between the skills necessary to the task and the abilities of the person trying it.
But it becomes noticeable when the person is abstract.  Take the sentence
“From the roof, you can see the airport.”
“You” here is indefinite.  The sentence is not about the eyesight of the person being spoken to.  It is just asserting that the seeing the airport is possible; nothing is blocking the view.
Or
“Anyone can tell that that politician is lying.”
It’s not about the perspicacity of “anyone”, the truth is just obvious.
Of course, “can” is also frequently used to describe personal abilities.  You can say* “Bob can run a 6-minute mile; Joe cannot.”
* “You can say” is the abstract form, so a native speaker would be unlikely to use the form “You are able to say...”

Yes, good points

There is a subtle difference but it may be hard to explain.
Imagine the following conversation:
Mother: Why haven't you tidied your bedroom?
Child: I was playing Fortnite.
Mother: Well you can do it right now.
Child: Oh, okay.
That is very different from "You are able to do it right now", which means "you have the capability".
We know that the child has the ability to do the task. The "can" in that example has an expectation - even a command - built into it.
Let us examine your examples:
"If we tell him what we see, he can give us directions." (This has an expectation that he will give directions)
"If we tell him what we see, he'll be able to give us directions." (This merely says that he has the ability to give them)

The difference there is very small but we can make it clearer by emphasis, e.g.
"I'm not sure where we are. Jack only gave us the address."
"Well, phone him up and he can damn well give us proper directions!"

This is a very good explanation. Yes, I think “can” sounds like the action is available or possible while “will be able to” tends to focus on the doer’s gaining ability to do so. Is this what you mean? @chasly - supports Monica

There is no practical difference. The most common meaning of "can" is "able to", or in legal contexts, "is permitted to do" (the opposite of 'is prohibited from doing')
